# Is the `finite index' condition in this proof necessary?

Tags: group-theory

In Koblitz's Modular Forms and Elliptic Curves, chapter 4, we take a subgroup $\Gamma'\subset\Gamma_0(4)\subset\Gamma=SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ of finite index in $\Gamma_0(4)$ and hence in $\Gamma$. He says *therefore* the intersection $\Gamma'\cap\Gamma_{\infty}$, where
\begin{equation}\Gamma_{\infty}=\bigg\{\pm
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & j\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}:j\in\mathbb{Z}\bigg\},
\end{equation}
is of the form
\begin{equation}\pm\bigg\{
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & h\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}^j:j\in\mathbb{Z}\bigg\},
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\bigg\{
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & h\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}^j:j\in\mathbb{Z}\bigg\},
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}\bigg\{
\bigg(-\begin{pmatrix}
1 & h\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\bigg)^j:j\in\mathbb{Z}\bigg\}.
\end{equation}
I would have thought that these are the only possible subgroups of $\Gamma_{\infty}$. What about finite index is necessary for this?

Comment: Well, finite-index is needed to guarantee $h$ is nonzero. Maybe that's used later?

Comment: @SeanEberhard Yes, the chapter is about finding half integral weight modular forms to be $h$-periodic (up to a constant factor). So $h$ being zero would somewhat negate this. Koblitz's phrasing doesn't quite imply this reading in my opinion, but it would make sense if this is what he meant.